# RxJs subscribeTo.js observable check works in Chrome, but fails in Chrome Incognito, MS Edge, and Firefox

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

In my Anguar(7) project, I use [redux-observable](https://redux-observable.js.org/) to do my [redux](https://redux.js.org/) side effects.

My code works in Chrome, but the exact same build fails in Chrome Incognito, MS Edge, and Firefox. The error I get is the following:

```
ERROR TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
    at subscribeTo (subscribeTo.js:58)
    at from (from.js:17)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.project (createEpicMiddleware.js:36)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push.../../../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (mergeMap.js:61)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push.../../../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._next (mergeMap.js:51)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push.../../../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at MapSubscriber.push.../../../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:41)
    at MapSubscriber.push.../../../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at Subject.push.../../../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject.next (Subject.js:47)
    at Function.epicMiddleware.run (createEpicMiddleware.js:62)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (redux.configuration.ts:50)
```

As you can see, the error is thrown in redux-observable's createEpicMiddleware, and this is caused by a check in RxJs [subscribeTo.js](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/util/subscribeTo.ts).

I then tried to dig into the [subscribeTo.js](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/util/subscribeTo.ts), after reading a response from [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3949). At the end of it, user Agraphie comments that a check in subscribeTo.js fails. I checked this, and sure enough, the check works in standard Chrome, but fails in all other browsers. My checking code added to subscribeTo.js looks like this:

```
export var subscribeTo = function (result) {
    if (isObservable(result)) {
        result.pipe(filter(x => x && x.type === 'GET_PLATFORM_SUCCESS')).subscribe(x => {
            console.log('Incoming value', result);
            console.log(`result && typeof result[Symbol_observable] === 'function': \n`, result && typeof result[Symbol_observable] === 'function');
            console.log('---------------------------')
        });
    }
    ...
```

The result can be seen in below screenshot (left side is standard Chrome, right side is Chrome Incognito)

[image]

Note the Observable IS an observable. It even passes RxJs's own isObservable test. So why does it fail the checks further below?

If you look close  above, you can see that the incoming observable's **proto** looks different from the left and right side. More precisely, the left side has the function property `Symbol(observable): f ()`, and the right side doesn't. In opposite, the right side has `@@observable: f ()`.

In short, the check `result && typeof result[Symbol_observable] === 'function'` is the cause of the error, since Symbol_observable is missing. As far as I can see.

### Dependencies and versions

I use

- angular 7.0.2
- rxjs 6.3.3
- rxjs-compat 6.3.3
- redux-observable 1.0.0 (they use rxjs 6 - [package.json](https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable/blob/master/package.json))).

### My questions

Why does this happen?
How can I fix it?

I have looked at [symbol-observable](https://github.com/benlesh/symbol-observable), but I'm not sure how to use it, or if that is even a good solution.

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3828

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same issue, with nearly the same config.

After some research I checked all imports and changed all imports from (`rxjs/internal/operators`)

```
import { catchError, flatMap, map, skipWhile } from 'rxjs/internal/operators';
```

to (`rxjs/operators`)

```
import { catchError, flatMap, map, skipWhile } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

This fixed the issue with Firefox, Chrome Incognito, ...

Cheers

Comment: I can also add that the problem was NOT with RxJs, as I thought it was in my question. Bad imports + some bad project architecture was at fault.

Comment: @MartinJH could you please provide more information about how you solved the issue, I have the exact same problem and I fixed the imports but I still have the same issues

Comment: Sorry about the "not so meaty" comment ;) Another part of my problem was the way the whole project was structured. We have both standard npm packages AND angular libraries in our project. We use https://redux-observable.js.org/ to create side effects via what they call "Epics". We had the base part of our epics in the npm packages, and the angular implementation in the angular libray, inheriting from the base type. This inheritance across libraries kind of "broke" the observable type, resulting in the error. The solution was to move everything epic related into the angular libraries.

Comment: Forgot to tag you above @ziz194

Comment: @MartinJH in the meanwhile I fixed the problem as well :) I am using another npm package that I created which exposes redux-observable, but it had a different rxjs version, so basically I had two different sources for rxjs in my project what I think made the error. The solution was just to keep one rxjs and move redux-obserfvable to my main project and not from the npm package

Comment: @ziz194 Super nice! It can be so hard to debug those kind of errors. Hopefully your comment will help someone as well :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with `rxjs/index`.

changing from:

```
import { of, from, combineLatest, ... } from `rxjs/index`
```

to:

```
import { of, from, combineLatest, ... } from `rxjs`
```

Fixed it.

Good Luck :)